# Mysql query for within a specific date

Tags: mysql

I need to retrieve data from within a specific date range.Anybody can help me to create a query to getting the information within date range 12-12-2009 to 12-15-2009 from a mysql table.(including 12 and 15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function in php first

```
function ChangeDateforDB($inputdate) {
  if($inputdate>0) {
    $month  = substr($inputdate,0,2);
    $date = substr($inputdate,3,2);
    $year  = substr($inputdate,6,4);
    $show = $year."-".$month."-".$date;
    return $show;
  }
}
```

After that you can use this in query like this in the checking condition,

```
checkdate >= '".ChangeDateforDB($fromdate)."' and checkdate <= '".ChangeDateforDB($todate)."'
```

Check this one, you can get the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE timestamp BETWEEN "2009-12-12" AND "2009-12-15"`

Comment: Although, on second thought, I'm not sure if this would select 12 and 15 or not. It would be nice if it did, since this is pretty much the most *elegant* way to select date ranges. It just goes downhill from here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ... WHERE DATEDIFF('2009-12-15',yourdatefield) <= 3 ...
```